# Representation of quotient group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Hello,
My question is about the relation between representations of a Lie group and its quotient.
Let $G$ be a compact lie group and $H$ a central subgroup of $G$. What is the relation between representations of $G$ and those of $G/H$? Exactly, I want to know that, is any representation of $G/H$ correspond to a representation of $G$ which is trivial on $H$?
* All representations are in a fixed vector space.
* It can be supposed that $G$ is semisimple or simple, if it is necessary.

Comment: This is more a question about the first (or second?) isomorphism theorem than anything else, and hence more appropriate for math.stackexchange. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $H$ is closed (i.e. not some irrational-flow subgroup inside the closed subgroup $Z(G)$).